# Html.BeginForm sends a null parameter to the relevant action (MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I am trying to have a form, where I edit a user account and in there I add roles using the Chosen plugin. For this I have created a view model:

```
public class UserAccountViewModel
{
    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList RolesSelectList { get; set; }
    public UserAccountViewModel() { }
    public UserAccountViewModel(UserAccount userAccount, List<RolesAccount> AllRoles)
    {
        UserAccount = userAccount;
        RolesSelectList = new MultiSelectList(AllRoles, "Id", "Name", UserAccount.Roles.Select(r=>r.Id).ToList());
    }
} // class UserAccountViewModel
```

Where UserAccount contains info such as an ID, username, password, etc. and a navigation property called Roles.

```
// Most of the members are stripped for clarity
public class UserAccount
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }        
    public string Username{ get; set; }       
    public string Email{ get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolesAccount> Roles { get; set; }
 } // end class UserAccount
```

In the edit form (razor) I have code such as the following (most fields have been removed by me):

```
@model LoginModule.UserAccountViewModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>UserAccount</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserAccount.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAccount.Username, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAccount.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAccount.Username)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("RolesOfUser",
                                Model.RolesSelectList,
                                new
                                {
                                    @class = "chzn-select",
                                    data_placeholder = "Choose roles...",
                                    style = "width:350px;"
                                }) 
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The problem I have is that when I click Submit, the controller receives a null parameter.

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserAccountViewModel useraccount)
```

I think I am not understanding the binding mechanism correctly. My experience so far has been that the model is populated automatically but in this case something is messing it up.

Why am I receiving a null parameter? Can someone point me in the right direction please? I have read many articles but I am getting nowhere.

How can I get the data I am looking for which in this case is represented by the UserAccount class, including the Roles? I am able to use other ways I retrieving the data, but I would prefer to use the Chosen plugin.

Comment: `public ActionResult Edit([FromBody] UserAccountViewModel useraccount)`

Comment: Are you passing your model to your view in the Get Action Method?

Comment: @Moe, I am using the Post Method.

Comment: @Chet, I tried and I cannot use FromBody. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? Is it giving a compile error, or adding it isn't solving your problem?

Comment: I am not sure why you even hit your controller if you dont specify which action to post to. Try Html.BeginForm("Edit", "<ControllerName>", FormMethod.Post) and attributing your Action with [HttpPost].

Comment: [FromBody] requires System.Web.Http, which when added as a reference creates an error with [HttpPost] from System.Web.Mvc (the type or namespace ... cannot be found). I am unable to use both references.  In a few words I am using an MVC controller.

Comment: @Georg. As far as I know FormMethod.Post is the default.  The Action is attributed with [HttpPost] already.

Answer (score 0):

After three days of struggling with this issue, I started to work on another PC for reasons unrelated to this problem and everything started to work again. There is no difference between the two PC in terms of Visual Studio versions and the branch used. After making a few code changes on another controller, and went back to the initial PC, the program started to work there as well.

Comment: That's the way it goes sometimes. I can't tell you how many times something weird like that happened to me over the years.